# How do I return a boolean from a Java program to a CentOS shell script?

Tags: java, linux, shell, centos

A shell script run on a CentOS 7 server needs to pass three parameters to a Java program, and then read a Boolean value returned by the Java program as a result of operations done on the three parameters.  **What specific changes do I need to make to the code below in order to return the Boolean value into the shell script?**

Here is a first attempt at the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ARG0=0
ARG1=0 
ARG2=0
CLASSPATH=/path/to/classes
echo -n "Enter zeroth arg: "
read ARG0
echo -n "Enter first arg: "
read ARG1
echo -n "Enter second arg: "
read ARG2
java -cp $CLASSPATH my.package.SomeClass[ARG0, ARG1, ARG2]
#How do I return the Boolean from the Java class into this shell script
```

Here is the Java class:

```
public class SomeClass {

private static Boolean passes = false;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String arg0 = null;
    String arg1 = null;
    String arg2 = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        if(i==0){arg0=args[i];}
        if(i==1){arg1=args[i];}
        if(i==2){arg2=args[i];}
    }
    
    if(!arg0.equals(null) && !arg1.equals(null) && !arg2.equals(null)){
        passes = doSomeTest(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }
    else{passes = false;}
}

public static boolean doSomeTest(String arg0, String arg1, String arg2){
    if(passes_test){return true;}
    else{return false;}
}

public static boolean getPasses(){return passes;}

}
```

Comment: The for loop isn't necessary. You can simply write `String arg0 = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : null;`, `String arg1 = args.length > 1 ? args[1] : null` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`System.exit(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) function to return a status code. This is done instead of `main` returning an `int`, as in C, C++, C#, etc.

Normally, `0` means success and anything else means failure.

Here, it looks like at the end of your `main` method you'll want to `System.exit(passes ? 0 : 1);`

In bash you can read the status code by using the `$?` variable. How you use it really depends on, well, how you use it later in your script. However, you don't need to change anything in the line that starts your Java program.

If you want a conditional based on the status code of your Java program, you can do the following after your `java -cp ...` call:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    abc
else
    xyz
fi
```

Comment: Can you show the actual code?  Shell scripts are new to me.  I need to see what the shell script looks like, and what the java has to look like to get the right value into the shell.  I imagine others finding this will have a similar need for clarity. Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying to write: `$RESULT = java -cp $CLASSPATH my.package.SomeClass ARG0 ARG1 ARG2`?  Somehow I think the syntax to populate the variable is a little different.  **Can you please show the correct syntax for populating the $? variable to use inside the shell script?**  Including a valid example of a name for the variable.  Thank you.

Comment: @CodeMed Just running the `java -cp ...` command (just like running any command) *sets `$?` for you*. No need to store it. Take a look at the examples [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html).

Comment: For this to be a usable answer, the shell needs to be able to perform abc if `$?` returns `true`, but perform xyz if `$?` returns `false`.  I assumed that meant populating the variable.  Can you please at least show how to do the `if...else` in the shell script with the returned value if you do not think it should be stored?

Comment: @CodeMed What I meant by my last comment was that *you* do not need to store it yourself, not that it doesn't need to be stored at *all*. What I was saying is that the status code of the last command is *always* available to you through the use of the `$?` variable. Anyway, I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for being so responsive.

Comment: @CodeMed Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

A java program can return a value by explicitly calling `System.exit(ret_value)`, where `ret_value` is an integer. So, you could do this at the end of main:

```
int ret = passes ? 1 : 0;
System.exit(ret);
```

Comment: So then what does the shell program need to look like in order to harvest this value?